# How to access to all ftp files via one file?

Tags: php

Is it possible to create .php file and when I access it, I can also access all my other ftp files? Download them, edit them or upload other files. It would be very comfortable.

Comment: What do you mean by "access"?

Comment: So you need a FTP web GUI written in PHP?

Comment: You can create a php file that connects to an FTP server, downloads files, edits them and then uploads them back. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've used this in the past:

> [File Thingie • PHP File Manager](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/tour)

It's nice and simple and is just a single php file.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [PHP File Manager](http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/)?

I had good results with [File Thingie](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/) myself.